# How to tell whether an executable was compiled for the present machine?

Tags: c, shell, gcc, compiler-construction, portability

I have some c code that I compile and run, in a directory that is accessible from many different unix computers (various linux and mac, occasionally others), with different OS's obviously needing different executables.

I have a simple shell script that invokes the appropriate executable, `prog.$OSTYPE.$MACHTYPE`, compiling it first if necessary.  This is very simple (although it requires using `csh` in order to have `$OSTYPE` and `$MACHTYPE` be reliably defined) and it almost works.

However, it turns out that even `$OSTYPE` and `$MACHTYPE` are not enough: for example, compiling on OSX 10.5 yields an executable `prog.darwin.i386` which, when invoked on OSX 10.4, crashes instantly.

Yes, recompiling every time I want to run the program is one way to solve this, but it seems excessive.  I know having a `bin` directory on every machine is a standard solution, but a non-root user may not have much write access outside their home directory (which is common to all the machines).

So my question is, is there a better approach?  The compiler (often gcc) obviously knows what kind of system it is compiling for -- is there a good portable way to find out what "kind of system" my script is running on, so it can invoke the correct executable, instead of one with undefined behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `gcc -v` to figure out what the installed/runnable gcc thinks is the target arch for hosted compiling (something like `$(gcc -v 2>&1 | grep Target: | sed 's/.*: *//')` in bash)

**edit**

If you really want to be able to do this without having anything in particular installed, you could extract the `config.guess` script from gcc (its in the top level directory of any gcc source package) and run that.  Unfortunately this won't work for all systems and might not exactly match what the system gcc package uses for some distributions, but this is the script used to configure gcc for building unless you explicitly override it...

Comment: If gcc isn't present, `bash --version` similarly tells you what target bash was compiled for (and bash is typically present and properly compiled on all systems).  (This can differ from gcc's target.)

Comment: This gives exactly the info I want, but it would be nicer if it didn't depend on gcc (although these days maybe everything has gcc).  Even on a machine with no compiler at all (don't laugh, it's an optional install on macs), it would be nice for my script to see that another machine of the same architecture had already produced an executable that could now be used (this being the best you could hope for in that case -- also more robust than recompiling every time).

Answer (score 2):

try to use `file` command from shell prompt

Comment: This is great for seeing what system executables were compiled for.

Comment: But it doesn't indicate what the current system is.  Even querying executables in /bin doesn't help if they are fat (then "file" lists multiple architectures, and you have to guess what yours is).

Answer (score 0):

Download some open source packages written in C and have a look at the file ./configure which is basically a large shell script that collects info from many sources, often by compiling and running short C programs. This will tell you everything that you need to know.

Since you are dealing with recent Mac OS X make sure you choose a package that is currently being maintained and supports OS X versions.