# Determine if an executable can be run on current machine

Tags: bash, executable

I'm using Docker to build my binaries so the result is in a Linux executable format. However at times, I would like to re-build the binaries and run them on an OS X machine (or BSD).

Is there a way using `/bin/bash` to determine if an executable is in the right format for the currently running machine so that I can **automatically rebuild them as necessary**?

Comment: On OSX you can use `otool -L /path/to/excutable`. On Linux you can use `ldd -r /path/to/executable`.

Comment: @alvits you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Build two binaries and tag them and fetch/use the right one per-target machine type?

Comment: @EtanReisner I thought of that at first but a simple bash if/else is much simpler at the moment :)

Comment: I don't agree that rebuilding your binaries all the time is simpler but you can do what you want.

Comment: The rebuilding will only happen every once in a big while and nope, modifying the build script to target multiple os and also making sure all other scripts can switch between them is anything but simpler. Plus only one version of them is ever going to be used at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell whether an executable was compiled for the present machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5656257/608639)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X you can use `otool` to check the executable. The `-L` switch displays the names and version numbers of the shared libraries that  the  object file uses, as well as the shared library ID if the file is a shared library.

`otool -L /path/to/executable`

Sample output looks like this:

```
/bin/ls:
    /usr/lib/libutil.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib (compatibility version 5.4.0, current version 5.4.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

On Linux you can use `ldd`. This is equivalent to OS X `otool`.

`ldd -r /path/to/executable`.